# Tkinter Make Grid Fit Frame Size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am wondering if there is a way to make a `grids` `rows` and `columns` fit the size of the `Frame` that is set. So that if I create a `Frame` and set its size that the `grid` will fit the size of the `Frame`.

This is what I tried so far:

```py
window = Tk()

frame = Frame(window)
frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=200, height=200)
title = Label(frame, text="The Title", bg="cornflower blue", height=2)
title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
sort_button = Button(frame, text="The Button", relief="groove", height=2, bg="maroon1",)
sort_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

window.mainloop()
```

> For example this is the output of my current code:

[image]

> But this is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a weight to the columns of your frame.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

frame = Frame(window,bg="yellow")

...

frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```